# What does box shading mean in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have imported MySQL database into EA and found that some tables depicted as dimmed rectangles and another ones -- as shaded rectangles:

[image]

The majority is dimmed.

What does it mean and how to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either a [diagram filter](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/building_models/diagram_filters_window.html) or a [visual filter](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/business_analysis_tools/tools_ba_visual_filters.html). Switch it off and you should be fine.